# Merging 2 arraylists into one

Tags: java, arrays, list, merge

I am trying to combine 2 arraylists into 1. I am receiving incompatible types error when i compile. I have no clue  where my mistake is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ArrayList<Course> myCourse = new ArrayList<Course>();
        myCourse.add(coursesTaken);
        myCourse.add(currentSemesterCourses);
```

Comment: When you're posting a question regarding an error, please include (copy and paste) the actual error message and stack trace in your question. Also, make sure you post all relevant code - the error is about incompatible *types*, but you don't include the declarations of `coursesTaken` and `currentSemesterCourses`, so we can't see what their *types* are.

Answer (score 2):

use [ArrayList#addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) that appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator.

```
myCourse.addAll(coursesTaken);
```

instead of

```
myCourse.add(coursesTaken);
```

I hope `coursesTaken` is a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) that contains item of type `Course` or any subclass of `Course`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [ArrayList.addAll(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29), and you could use the [ArrayList(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) constructor as well -

```
ArrayList<Course> myCourse = new ArrayList<Course>(coursesTaken);
myCourse.addAll(currentSemesterCourses);
```